# second submit form is not working in php app for facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a facebook app in php that working without any problem of authentication. so users log in and the app gets required permissions and they navigate through the pages. but 
I have a page called sender.php that need to repeat 8 times.

So here is the scenario that is not working:
1)users are in sender.php 
2)they click submit,(as action form is set to "sender.php") the browser again shows sender.php form
3) a user again enter something in text input, and click on submit button
4) a blank page shows without anything; 
(note thatit is only works for the first click, for second time it only shows a blank page without any errors or notice.)

here is html code in sender.php:(the first php codes using here are the same for the rest of php pages and working without any error)

```
<?php
require_once("config.php");
require_once("database.php");
require_once("facebook_include1.php");
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$me = $facebook->api('/me');
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if (isset($_GET['moneySent'])) {
$moneySent = round($_GET['moneySent']);
$senderBalance = $_GET['balance'];  
$senderRate = $_GET['senderRate'];  
$receiverRate = $_GET['receiverRate'];
}
    ?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function validateForm() {   
   var isValid = true;
   var moneySent = document.getElementById("moneySent").value;
   var balance = document.getElementById("balance").value;
       if (!document.getElementById("moneySent").value.length)
            {
              delete window.alert;
              alert("Please enter an amount you want to send!.");
              isValid = false;
            }
            else if (isNaN(moneySent))
              {
              delete window.alert;
              alert("Please enter a numeric value.");
              isValid = false;

              }
               else if (Math.round(moneySent) > balance) {

               delete window.alert;
               alert("The amount you want to send should be     less than your balance.");
                isValid = false;
                }
               return isValid;
           }
  </script>
  <form action="sender.php" method="get" name="sendFor" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
   <div class="yui-u">
     <input type="text" id="moneySent" name="moneySent" style="width:100px"/>
     <input type="hidden" name="balance" id="balance" value='<?php echo $senderBalance ?>'/>
     <input type="hidden" name="senderRate" id="senderRate" value='<?php echo $senderRate ?>'/>
     <input type="hidden" name="receiverRate" id="receiverRate" value='<?php echo $receiverRate ?>'/>
      </div>
      <div class="yui-u">
      <input type="submit" name="btnsearch" id="btnsearch" value="    Send &gt;    " class="search" style="margin-left:-6.5px" /><br />
    </div>
  </form>
```

any thought is really appreciated. I am using php5 and apache with the latest facebook sdk for php.

UPDATED:
I've tested in Firefox. However, if I use IE8 and add target="_blank" to the form tag, the page is going out of facebook canvas but start working normally, any idea?

Comment: What code is inside your `sender.php` file?

Comment: the above code is inside sender.php, you mean the whole codes for sender.php?

Comment: You can leave out the `sender.php` in your form action (`action=""`) or try `action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>"`. Give that a try.

Comment: Plus, I think what you need is a `post` method, and not a `get`, am not 100% sure but forms are usually set as `post` when sending using email. Try changing all your `($_GET[` to `($_POST[`. Working with a `copy` of your code, of course. ;-)

Comment: Did you by chance change `method="get"` to `method="post"` when changing all the `$_GET`s to `$_POST`?

Comment: yeah, changed both, still not working

Comment: You mentioned `"they are redirected to sender.php..."`, do you have a `header("location:.....` anywhere in your other PHP files? Plus, you have some `JS` happening here in `onsubmit="return validateForm();` which could play a role, but without seeing the rest of your code, is a bit hard for me to tell.

Comment: Plus this line `$moneySent = round($_GET['moneySent']);` I don't quite understand. You're doing calculations on something?

Comment: You're closing your PHP tags also (prematuraly) in `$user = $facebook->getUser(); ?> <? if (isset($_GET['moneySent'])) {`. Try keeping everything together such as `$user = $facebook->getUser(); if (isset($_GET['moneySent'])) {`. Or try adding `php` to `<?`

Comment: updated the code and question, both all in one <?php tag

Comment: moneySent is float, so it is rounding it

Comment: I can still see the bunched up `?><?` in your edit. Try removing those, or change `<?` to `<?php`. Seems like it's closing prematurely.

Comment: I haven't the foggiest idea at this point now. Only inconsistency I can see is that you have `./` in `require_once("./config.php");` but not the others. I doubt that has anything to do with it, but I guess you could give it a shot and make them all the same. Problem may not even lie in your `sender.php`. Have you tried it without the `JS`?

Comment: I just thought of something. Try if `(isset($_GET['sendFor'])) {` instead of `if (isset($_GET['moneySent'])) {`, see what that gives.

Comment: i tried without js and changed the ./ to be the same with others. still the issue is there, BTW, thanks for helping me;)

Comment: Sorry, but I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed action="sender.php" to action="#" and it is working in both IE and firefox.
Not sure what is the difference though!!